# Force close error every time layout is changed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, eclipse-adt

My app force closes every time I mess with the Relative Layout's positioning now and then. I have to arbitrarily keep re-positioning them for the app to work again. Or position them all at the topmost left corner and then re arrange them.

I'm using Eclipse.

Why does this happen? Is there a way I can avoid this?

**[EDIT]**

> 07-22 21:39:22.042: D/dalvikvm(520): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 291K, 52%
> free 2718K/5639K, external 741K/1038K, paused 51ms
>
> 07-22 21:39:22.422: D/AndroidRuntime(520): Shutting down VM
> 07-22 21:39:22.432: W/dalvikvm(520): threadid=1: thread exiting with
> uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
>
> 07-22 21:39:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(520): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 07-22 21:39:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(520): java.lang.RuntimeException:
> Unable to start activity
>
> ComponentInfo{com.android.tapme/com.android.tapme.TapMe}:
> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
>
> 07-22 21:39:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(520):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
>
> 07-22 21:39:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(520):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>
> 07-22 21:39:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(520):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>
> 07-22 21:39:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(520):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
>
> 07-22 21:39:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(520):    at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 07-22 21:39:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(520):    at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>
> 07-22 21:39:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(520):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>
> 07-22 21:39:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(520):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 07-22 21:39:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(520):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>
> 07-22 21:39:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(520):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>
> 07-22 21:39:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(520):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>
> 07-22 21:39:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(520):    at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 07-22 21:39:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(520): Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
>
> 07-22 21:39:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(520):    at
> com.android.tapme.TapMe.onCreate(TapMe.java:26)
>
> 07-22 21:39:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(520):    at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>
> 07-22 21:39:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(520):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
> 07-22 21:39:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(520):    ... 11 more

**[EDIT]**

I edited the layout randomly and finally got it to work. I then added a progress bar and voila! Force close errors again. Here's the log.

> 07-26 00:06:57.445: D/AndroidRuntime(876): Shutting down VM
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.465: W/dalvikvm(876): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.android.tapme/com.android.tapme.TapMe}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876):    at com.android.tapme.TapMe.(TapMe.java:17)
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
>
> 07-26 00:06:57.486: E/AndroidRuntime(876):    ... 11 more

Answer (score 0):

In a RelativeLayout, all the children elements are placed relative to each other.

Here's a code snippet.

```
android:layout_below="@id/elementOne"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/elementTwo"
```

So, mess with one of them, you mess with everything.

Comment: How's that answering my question? I get that the positions will be changed. Why is there a FATAL EXCEPTION caused?